# Recaptcha doesn't load dynamically in DNN module using Recaptcha.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, recaptcha

I've a problem to load Google Recaptcha control when I try to assign Public & Private Keys dynamically in code behind. It works fine in simple ASP.Net website but It doesn't work when I integrate it in DNN module.

**Error Message:** reCAPTCHA needs to be configured with a public & private key.

**Stack trace:**

> DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: reCAPTCHA needs to be configured with a public & private key. ---> System.ApplicationException: reCAPTCHA needs to be configured with a public & private key.     at Recaptcha.RecaptchaControl.OnInit(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)     at System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.Add(Control child)     at DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.ModuleHost.InjectModuleContent(Control content)     at DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.ModuleHost.CreateChildControls()     at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

**Markup:**

```
<googleCaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="ctlRecaptcha" runat="server" />
```

**Code-behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ctlRecaptcha.PublicKey = "xyz";
    ctlRecaptcha.PrivateKey = "abc";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually have a tutorial on DNNHero.com that teaches on creating a [custom DNN registration with the Google Recaptcha](http://www.dnnhero.com/Premium/Tutorial/ArticleID/313/Custom-Registration-with-reCAPTCHA-Overview-and-Demonstration-part-1-4).  It includes a video and code project.

Looking at my code, I included the attributes for publickey and privatekey on my ascx, but with dummy values:

```
<googleCaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="ctlRecaptcha" runat="server" PublicKey="your_public_key" PrivateKey="your_private_key"/>
```

I set the attribute values like you did in my Page_Load event.  This worked for me.  Give it a try and comment if it still throw the error.